# How tunelength parameter works in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using following code to implement elastic net using R

```
model <- train(
Sales ~., data = train_data, method = "glmnet",
trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
tuneLength = 10
)
```

I'm confused about tunelength paramater. In Cran I'm seeing that

> To change the candidate values of the tuning parameter, either of the 
>   tuneLength or tuneGrid arguments can be used. The train function can 
>   generate a candidate set of parameter values and the tuneLength
>   argument  controls how many are evaluated. In the case of PLS, the
>   function uses a  sequence of integers from 1 to tuneLength. If we want
>   to evaluate all  integers between 1 and 15, setting tuneLength = 15
>   would achieve this

But train function is taking dependent & independent variable from my data then how it's using tuneLength parameter? Can you please help me understand?

Answer (score 3):

In `caret` the `train()` function has a number of arguments to help select the "optimal" tuning parameters for your chosen model.

Model tuning is explained in detail in package documentation [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html).

Users can customize the tuning process by specifying a grid of possible parameter values that the model will use when training the model.

For some models, the use of `tuneLength` is an alternative to specifying a `tuneGrid`.

For example, one method of searching for the 'optimal' model parameters is using random selection. In this case the `tuneLength` argument is used to control the number of combinations generated by this random tuning parameter search.

> To use random search, another option is available in trainControl called search. Possible values of this argument are "grid" and "random". The built-in models contained in caret contain code to generate random tuning parameter combinations. The total number of unique combinations is specified by the tuneLength option to train.

It is covered in more detail here:
http://topepo.github.io/caret/random-hyperparameter-search.html

It is important to check the model you are using in the train function and look at which tuning parameters are used for that model. It will then be easier to understand how to correctly customize the model fitting process.

For your example of using `method = 'glmnet'` here is a comparison using `tuneGrid` and `tuneLength` (taken from [package tests](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/glmnet.R)):

```
cctrl1 <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, returnResamp = "all",
                       classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

test_class_cv_model <- train(trainX, trainY, 
                             method = "glmnet", 
                             trControl = cctrl1,
                             metric = "ROC",
                             preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                             tuneGrid = expand.grid(.alpha = seq(.05, 1, length = 15),
                                                    .lambda = c((1:5)/10)))
```

```
cctrlR <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, returnResamp = "all", search = "random")


test_class_rand <- train(trainX, trainY, 
                         method = "glmnet", 
                         trControl = cctrlR,
                         tuneLength = 4)
```